# $n^\text{th}$ derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, polynomials

I'm trying to show that $f^{n+1}(x)=0$. I've calculated the derivatives of $f(x)=2x^{5}+3x^{4}+4$.

$f'(x)=10x^{4}+12x^{3}$

$f''(x)=40x^{3}+36x^{2}$

$f'''(x)=120x^{2}+72$

$f^{4}(x)=240x+72$

$f^{5}(x)=240$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from there?

Comment: The derivative of a constant function is $0$

Comment: The derivative of a constant function is $0$. You've used that fact all along.

Comment: @EthanBolker oh so I've already proven that $f^{n+1}(x) =0$ ?

Comment: Yes, for any $n > 5$.

Comment: For any $n>4$ it's true.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, assume
$$P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$$
then
$$\begin{align}
P'(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^n ka_kx^{k-1} \\
P''(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^nk(k-1)a_kx^{k-2} \\
...\\
P^{(n)}(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^nn!a_kx^0 \end{align}$$Finally,$$
P^{(n+1)}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n(n!a_k)' = \sum_{k=0}^n0 = 0$$
Hence, for any polynomial of degree $\leqslant n$, we have $P^{(n+1)}(x) \equiv 0$.

Comment: Or less than degree $n$.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó Definitely!

Answer (score 0):

You are done.

$f^5(x) = 240$ and that is a constant.  The derivative of a constant function is $0$ so $f^6(x) = 0$.  And $0$ is a constant function so it's derivative is $0$ and so by induction.

Base case: $f^6(x) = 0$.

Induction step: If $f^n(x) = 0$, then $f^{n+1}(x) = (0)' = 0$.

Conclusion:  $f^{n} = 0$ for all $n \ge 6$.